# Can I add a comment for xml element of layout file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I can add a comment for a  xml layout file using `<!--  -->` just like Code A.

Now I hope to add  a comment in xml element `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>`, but Code B doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
   <!-- This is a comment -->                          
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mvoice_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_voice_item"
        tools:itemCount="10"
    />
```

**Code B**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/mvoice_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
   
    <!-- This is a comment -->    
    tools:listitem="@layout/layout_voice_item"
    tools:itemCount="10"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting inside a tag is not possible.

**But!** You can define your own **namespace** in parent ViewGroup:

```
xmlns:comment="http://com.anything.comment"
```

and comment any property of View with:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .......
    .......
    
    comment:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    comment:weight="1"
    comment:comment="Commented Text"
    tools:listitem="@layout/layout_voice_item"
    tools:itemCount="10"
/>
```